# Force HTTPS using only HTACCESS in SYMFONY

Tags: .htaccess, symfony1, https, symfony-1.4

We have a Symfony 1.4 project and are looking to force HTTPS for all pages in a symfony application using only the htaccess file. I know there are ways to do using filters but I want to know if it's possible to do without that first?

Here is the .HTACCESS file I currently am using but isn't working as expected...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

I've also tried without success:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I am sure there is some quirk I am missing in doing this with Symfony as this is an easy task to do straight away. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5880655/569101) ?

Comment: Yea I saw that one and tried to modify it so that ALL pages were forces to SSL, the example the user only wanted a few select locations to force SSL andthe rest to be regular HTTP. I am no whiz with .htaccess files so there is a chance I wasnt doing it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5880655/569101), try:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: No dice... I put in the URL https://www.mysite.com and login, once logged in the pages are HTTP

Comment: Just tried on my local machine, and it works like a charm. Could edit your post with your full `.htaccess` ?