# How to tell Symfony2 not to use https?

Tags: symfony, ssl

I have a Symfony2 website and domain with ssl. Every time I try to login or logout Symfony redirects me from http to https. I know that login should have secure connection, but right now I need to force Symfony not to use ssl. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Symfony2 configuration

### Via app/config/security.yml file

There you have probably set the `requires_channel` property to https.

```
access_control:
    - path: ^/login
      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
      requires_channel: https
```

So to not force the use of https, just **remove** this property.

Have a look at the [doc about forcing https or http with the security config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html).

### Via routing files

In routing files, you can force http or https with the `schemes` property.

```
secure:
    path:     /secure
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:secure }
    schemes:  [https]
```

So again, to not force the use of https, just **remove** that property.

Have a look at the [doc about forcing https or http with the routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html).

## Apache configuration

It is also possible to force https via `.htaccess`files with the rewrite module.
If the two previous ways didn't work, check your `.htacess` files for rewrite rules/conditions.

Comment: I don't have any requires_channel or schemes set. Does Symfony2 redirect login action to https if avalible? Or is it somwhere else set that when I try to login/logout I'm redirected to https (DNS or something)? This redirection occures only on login/logout

Comment: It's also possible to force https with .htaccess files. Check your .htaccess file(s). There is a post on SO about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703206/force-https-using-only-htaccess-in-symfony

Comment: ok, I found out that nginx config had something that forced ssl, when I turned that off everything works great, and your answer is the thing that I'll need to set https on certain things only. Thanks :)