# How to ignore https if its localhost?

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-3.3

I actually know how to force redirect to https or to http if its local, like below:

```
security.yml

 ...
 - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http, host: localhost$ }
 - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
 ...
```

but the problem is that, I have alot of redirections.

Is there easy way to ignore https for localhost? I couldn't find anything on symfony homepage or on google.

or is it something like below possible?

```
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https, host:!localhost$}
```

is it possible to ignore host?

Comment: I understand this is not the answer you are looking for, but you can use another security.yml for the dev environment or just redirect the whole site to https in production at the server level (Apache, nginx, ...) so that every request that touches your PHP app is always served via HTTPS and you do not need those firewall rules in security.yml

Answer (score 0):

try to modify .htaccess file and use server_name to check if localhost:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ==on

RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

check example [here](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony2-https-htaccess/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703206/force-https-using-only-htaccess-in-symfony)

Comment: thank you but I know already how to do it with .htaccess. I must solve it in security.yml