# How to config Symfony App in cpanel hosting with an ssl certificate (https) in Apache Virtual Host

Tags: symfony, ssl, https, cpanel

This is my scenario:

1. I have my Symfony 3.3 app deployed at my domain with cpanel in a dedicated hosting in Godaddy.
2. My document root is not public_html, it is a subfolder in public_html
3. With http I can access normally to my website
4. When I installed the ssl certificate in cpanel successfully and then I update my .htaccess under web folder to redirect to https, the site was redirected to public_html folder, not to public_html/subfolder/web, just like it was occur with http normally.

Please, some one can help me with this problem?

I hope that change my Symfony web folder to public_html folder are not the only solution.

**UPDATE 1**

My .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # start https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # end https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found the problem and the solution, that´s why I changed the title of the question, because the problem was not with Symfony, was with Apache virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments of Ramazan give me a new idea to search the solution. Well, I found it [here](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/changing-the-document-root-with-root-access)
To deploy my site in a subfolder into public_html I needed to change the virtual host configuration, but, I only modified the main file, not the _SSL config file.
Then, the solution in this link is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using security configuration. Here is a example https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/force_https.html

or routing

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/scheme.html

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the .htaccess is correct? or I need to use security configuration without .htaccess?

Comment: I suggest you examine this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703421/2210147

Comment: I tryed that, and this is what the browser are showing: The requested URL /en was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.      If I remove /en from the url then my problem persist, the site is redirect to public_html folder and not to public_html/subfolder/web

Comment: It is something like the document root for 443 is diferent of the document root for 80. My dedicated hosting is on GoDaddy. Do you know if I need to modify the virtual host config for 443 port?

Comment: Delete this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] Would you try this. RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: Thanks Ramazan, I already found the solution. I post an answer for my own question. But I didn´t achieved without your comments, that give me the idea to search in other direction. Was not a Symfony problem in this case, was the Apache Virtual Host configuration problem.